# I can't edit my mistake in the custom bounty message

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I added a bounty to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device) today. I wrote a custom message for it, but after I added the bounty I realized I had left an extra link at the bottom that I had meant to delete.

[image]

I also didn't realize that the links weren't clickable, so I would also like to delete the first link. But I can't. There is no way to edit the custom bounty message after the bounty has already been added.

Could we make the custom bounty message editable? Even 5 minutes would help.

Comment: Certainly not your mistake.